# Selecting days from a drop down in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new to polymer and I'm trying to create a `paper-card` with a 'list' that's dynamic. The premise goes like this, "user selects a day of the week from a drop down menu, a start time and and end time. When the press the "plus" button a new row is created, but the drop-down menu now does *not* include an already used day of the week." I have the layout semi-working, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle each current/new row with the add button.[image: Concept of what I'm trying to do]

[image]

Comment: I can't recognise concrete question here?!

Comment: How can I get the "+" button to add an additional row like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are varios options, it will be nice if you share your code.

But here is one general answer:

In Polymer, recommended way of manipulating the DOM is by manipulating the data.

For example,

- if you have list of **rows** as: var rows_array = [....];

Supose you are displaying the list using iron-list as:

```
<iron-list data="rows_array">
  <template>
  ...
  <template>
</iron-list>
```

- On-click on "+" button add new element to the rows_array, and that will add row in the iron-list immediately.

Comment: Help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566067/data-binding-between-parent-child-in-polymer1-0/44568308#44568308