# Data binding/updating between parent and child using <content> tag in Polymer1.0

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a slider element that contains list of slides and a `img` to show hovered slide as shown below. I am binding `currentImage` between `custom-slide`(child) and `custom-slider`(parent)

**CASE I**

**custom-slider.html**

```
<template>
    <div>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
    </div>
    <img src="{{currentImage}}">
</template>
```

It works perfectly when I used like this.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <custom-slider>
    </custom-slider>
</body>
```

But when I change **index** and **custom-slider** html as shown below, it's not working. The hovered `custom-slide` not showing in the `img` tag. It's not getting updated.

**CASE II**

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <custom-slider>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
       <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
    </custom-slider>
</body>
```

**custom-slider.html**

```
<template>
    <div>
       <content select="custom-slide, [custom-slide]"></content>
    </div>
    <img src="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
</template>
```

No errors in the console as well.

I have a property called `currentImage` for both `custom-slide` and `custom-slider` as shown and even I used `notify: true` to the property.

```
currentImage: {
   type: String,
   value: 'some_image_url_by_default',
   notify: true
}
```

and on `mouseover` on `custom-slide` I have a event that is to update the customImage in `custom-slider`. The image url is updating in `custom-slide` but not in `custom-slider`. It is updating in both only when I used the first case code of my question.

**UPDATE**

When I have binding directly in the template of any Custom element then the binding is working. But when I have binding indirectly i.e, using `<content>` tag then the binding is not working. For example,

```
<parent-elem></parent-elem> // custom element
```

Parent element template

```
<dom-module id="parent-elem">
  <template>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
  </template>
  // Assume here in script I have a property name
</dom-module>
```

Like above, it is working.

But in the above code if I replace `<div>{{name}}</div>` with `<content></content>` and change

```
<parent-elem>
   <div>{{name}}</div>
</parent-elem> // custom element
```

then the binding is not working. Why? Then what is the use of having a `<content>` tag?

**EDIT**

[Plunker with problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZzGTB04LyrLDzx5OLrt?p=preview)

In that plunker check the images by hover them. First three are without content tag and next three are by using content tag. Give me the solution. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How will `binding` work in HTML? As `index.html` is not a polymer element you cannot bind properties there. And also as @KubaŠimonovský pointed you'll need to pass `currentImage` to `custom-slider` also.

Comment: `<img src="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>` is this a typo in SO only or in your code also?

Comment: it's just a typo in SO. But I tried @KubaS answer but didn't worked

Comment: If you understood my question and if you know how to solve it, please make a sample answer demo and put it here

Comment: The reason it didn't work is because you tried it in `index.html` and not polymer element. If you want to do it in index.html try using `dom-bind`.

Comment: one thing for sure, you should use `<img src$="{{currentImage}}" />` because if you don't add the `$` ten it's try to use the element class properties to share the value, but with `$` it's using the HTML attribute.
Also @a1626 is right, use `dom-bind` in the `index.html`

Comment: To which element I should use `dom-bind`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NvS9RJKri6PdAL8kqNom?p=preview) is a fork of your current plunkr. I've made two changes to it.

- Engulfed `index.html` in `dom-bind` so that polymer bindings can work.
- Replaced hard coded value of `current-image` for `phone-carousel` with binding, so that it can be updated on-hover

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes. very thank you. You are the one who actually deserves the upvotes and bounty. The hero of my question

Comment: I'll give the bounty after 2 hrs

Comment: But I didn't understand one thing that I don't know why some guys down-voted the question. Is that is bad way of asking question? I tried my best to ask

Comment: Please explain in detail

Comment: There can be lot of reasons for down vote. You might have got some of them because earlier there was not enough code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5):

you are not setting `currentImage` to `custom-slider` but only to `custom-slide`. So inside `custom-slider` you won't fint that property. That's the problem propably you are looking for.

edit your code to:

```
<custom-slider current-image="{{currentImage}}">
   <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
   <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
   <custom-slide current-image="{{currentImage}}"></custom-slide>
</custom-slider>
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that you can't do these things in `index.html` you need to wrap it into another file that will store `currentImage` property and notify about changes. So the only thing i did, was to wrap everything you had in `index.html` into new file which I called `wrapper-elements` (change it to watever you want)
I also edited something to make it more simple, so don't do ctrl+c and ctrl+v. Just copy `wrapper-elements` element only.

Here is working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/eElf4H6CQOVhahShyjBF?p=preview
(I hope it's right link. I have never did something in plnkr)

Comment: really hard to help when you say just not working. What is not working. property doesn't exists, or image is not shown or what. Some more info is needed here

Comment: image not showing. image in `custom-slide` is showing but on hover i am showing it in another div right, that's not showing

Comment: well, you didn't mentioned anything about hover at all, plus, you didn't post your code of `custom-slide` element. If you are setting something inside `custom-slide` and you need to propagate it to parent (`custom-slider`) then just add `notify:true` to definition of property `currentImage` inside `custom-slide`

Comment: oh i got it propably. Unfortunately, i have no idea, how to solve this at this moment. Provide working jsbin would help a lot. You are using old Polymer so i can't try it :(

Comment: Please create a Codepen or Jsbin to check your code in.

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem, because it's not required to add to every parent element some variable just to have it in the children. It's only required when the children it's in a Shadow DOM and created by the parent.

Comment: @adaliszk yep, it was just bad misunderstood, because question was really badly asked.

Comment: Finally, I successfully updated a plunker with my problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZzGTB04LyrLDzx5OLrt?p=preview

Comment: @Mr_Perfect done. I have edited my answer with working plnkr.

Comment: Can you please see **paper-carousel**? There it is working with childs in **index.html**?

Comment: `paper-carousel` has minified code so it's impossible to read something from it. Maybe he is using custom events (which is another way of how to do it). There are built-in methods in polymer like `fire`. you can `fire` some event and then listen to him somewhere else. So it's not using bindings. And it's also more customizable, because anywhere in project, you can just fire some event and image will change, but learn something about it on your own.

Comment: Is my question is that much bad? I don't know why people down-voted. I can give the bounty after 6hrs. I am getting popup like "You can award the bounty after 6hrs".